# composer auth.json not working / ignoring auth.json

Tags: php, gitlab, composer-php

i use the new [feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/) of gitlab the composer package registry.
It works fine but the authentication with the auth.json file dont work.

I done all steps in the documentation of gitlab and composer but no success.
I tried to store the auth.json file beside the composer.json file and at `%APPDATA%/Composer` but it makes no different. I get allways the same error message.

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md

If i use the inline authentication in the composer.json file at the repository object it works.
`{"repositories": [{"type": "composer", "url": "https://extremely:secret@repo.example.org"}]}`

I get following error message:

```
C:\path\to\project> composer update -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Loading config file C:\path\to\project/auth.json
Reading C:\path\to\project/auth.json
Checked CA file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\opeD84C.tmp: valid
Executing command (C:\path\to\project\ida.argo.data): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Running 1.10.10 (2020-08-03 11:35:19) with PHP 7.4.8 on Windows NT / 10.0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/group/8835906/-/packages/composer/packages.json


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/group/8835906/-/packages/composer/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/
  1.1 404 Not Found)


Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:441
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:105
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:695
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:506
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadRootServerFile() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:285
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->hasProviders() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:108
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:393
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:232
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:163
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:281
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:113
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:61
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:24
```

I hope someone can help me :) thx!

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab updated his documentation.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/index.html

You must use the `gitlab-token` configuration in the `auth.json`.

```
{
    "gitlab-token": {
       "gitlab.com": "<personal_access_token>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Arth's answer and for people ending up here who followed the Gitlab directions, but use a different port for a (local) gitlab server: add the port to the different configs.

composer.json

```
"config": {
    "gitlab-domains": [
        "<your gitlab domain>:<custom port>"
    ]
},
```

auth.json

```
{
    "gitlab-token": {
        "<your gitlab domain>:<custom port>": "<personal_access_token>"
    }
}
```

That got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit:

/home/{USER}/.config/composer/auth.json file

Comment: I would like to put the line under some syntax highlight but I can't since the edit queue is full. Please put 4 whitespaces before the pathname. Also please replace `{USER}` with `$USER` so it's a valid pathname in bash, shell-expanded :)